# How to format types implementing Display in rust?

Tags: rust, format

playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ed531c76be5298b858a05c705292a804

How can I format structs that implement the Display trait?
Seems a bit redundant to need to call to_string() on everything?

```
struct MyStruct();

impl std::fmt::Display for MyStruct {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "X")
    }
}

fn main() {
    
    let x = MyStruct{};
    let y = "Y";
    
    println!("{:_^9}", x); // WHY isnt this properly formatted?
    println!("{:_^9}", x.to_string());
    println!("{:_^9}", y);
}
```

outputs:

```
X
____X____
____Y____
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=365c3d3ee60cfa169042733aeb5e5e7b

Comment: Thanks @Stargateur - I would accept this as an answer, if I could.  I still think its a bit counter-intuative that the formatting happens at the deepest level of the calls.. a Gatcha of rust i guess. THANKYOU

Comment: well... feel free to make your own answer ^^, most rust display implementation don't use f. Must prefer have a custom display structure to handle option formating. Because this kind of formating option make sense for std type but not much for anything outside that